# Floated div - fill available width

Tags: html, css-float, width

I have to divs floated, one is on the left, the other on the right. What i want to do (without js) is that the right div fills the available space (width: 100%). The problem is, that the left div has an dynamic width, else I could simply use margin-left.
I also tried display: table-cell; but that won't allow me to use margin, only border-spacing.

Any suggestion?

Comment: How dynamic is the width of the left div??

Comment: i think it will be between 200 - 500px

Comment: You will have to define the widths of both sides.

Comment: and that is what i dont want to do. i want that the width of the left div is auto / not set and the right div fill up the available space (100%).

Comment: You might want to share some code so that we can see exactly see what you mean. Also, in the first sentence you mean 'two divs floated' right? If so, I'd suggest to change that for clarity! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it like this, works in IE8 and better, in FF, in Safari. You could use padding instead of margin, as in this example:

```
<style>
    .c_0 {
        display:        table;
        width:          100%;
        border:         4px solid orange;
    }

    .c_1 {
        display:        table-cell;
        width:          20%;
        border:         1px solid red;
        padding-right:  20px;
    }

    .c_2 {
        display:        table-cell;
        border:         1px solid blue;
    }
</style>

<div class="c_0">
    <div class="c_1">
        has a width and padding instead of margin
    </div>
    <div class="c_2">
        has the rest
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

This only works with **"%"** on the first row. I saw it too late, that you want pixels.

Comment: Question: As this answer doesn't solve the problem explicitly, should I delete it?

Comment: Hey, the % aren't the problem, i just want that the left div width is auto / not set, so its dynamic.
You don't have to delete it, even if it doesn't solve the problem, maybe it will help someone in few years ;)

Comment: And where does the column know from, that is has reached it maximum width?

Comment: Well as insertusernamehere says it will auto set the left for a right cell percentage marked width. As soon as you try and put a px there it won't work.

Comment: Basically if you are only gong to be setting by percentage then his is your answer...